# Rails has_many OR condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a task where Garage should fetch cars from User model or if User doesn't have cars Garage should fetch cars from itself.
Ideally, I want to have all rails API for has_many relation. Is there any chance to do that?

```
class Garage
  has_many :cars, through: :user || has_many :cars # pseudo-code
end
```

Comment: Perhaps your use case is not clear. Can you elaborate on the situation?

Comment: @sawa well, that situation happened after some structural changes in a database and the fastest solution of this problem is described in pseudo-code: keep that relation rails-like(I must have all methods that `has_many` provides) and at the same time to have that OR condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just name the associations differently and use a method to load the cars:

```
has_many :cars
has_many :user_cars, through: :user, source: :cars

def all_cars
  user_cars.presence || cars
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The full code necessary to solve your problem is unclear, but broadly speaking here's how I would go about performing this structural migration.

Firstly, define two clear associations:

```
class Garage < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_cars, through: :user, class_name: 'Car'
  has_many :cars
end
```

Then add some method(s) that attempt to fetch both, as you described:

```
class Garage < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_cars, through: :user, class_name: 'Car'
  has_many :cars

  def cars
    user_cars.presence || super
  end
end
```

Then, when the data has all been migrated to the new structure, you can delete the old association:

```
class Garage < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cars, through: :user
end
```